# Wildfly 14 does not find JDK classes

Tags: java-8, jboss, wildfly

I'm migrating an old system with Java7/JBoss7 to Java8/Wildfly14, it compiles ok, but when I try to deploy I get the following error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

I'm using JDK 1.8 to compile and to run Wildfly, but it turns out that this class is inside the JDK, so how is it possible that Wildfly doesn't find it ?

[screenshot http://167.99.212.126/jdk.jpg](http://167.99.212.126/jdk.jpg)

Comment: What is the full stack trace?

Comment: Also define how you start wildfly. Have you correctly setup your java specific environmental variables?

Comment: Can you check the java version on command prompt, not eclipse. This class ProviderImpl has been moved to different package in Java-9

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://docs.wildfly.org/14/Developer_Guide.html#accessing-jdk-classes
Not all JDK classes are available for deployments. In order to get access to them you need to explicitly describe them in jboss-deployment-structure.xml